# Boost Include_DIR for CMake

Tags: c++, boost, filesystems, cmake, boost-filesystem

Can someone tell me why I cannot succeed in including Boost in CMake. I have problem when I configure in CMake.

[image: Boost Folder]

[image: CMakeList File]

[image: CMake Configure]

Comment: Boost.Filesystem is not a header-only library.  Verify that it has been compiled and that `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR` is set to the directory containing the compiled library.

Answer (score 0):

Use set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "C:/Library/boost_1_56_0/lib")